# C++ Copy Constructor Error

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

Say I have the following piece of code:

```
class C1{
int x, y;

public:

    C1(int a, int b):x(a),y(b)
    {
        cout<<"const normal C1"<<endl;
    }
};

class C2 : protected C1
{
    int x, y;
    const int z;

public:
    C2(int u, int v, int w):C1(u,v),z(w)
    {
        cout<<"constr normal C2"<<endl;
    }
    C2(const C2 &a,int u, int v, int w):C1(u,v),z(w)
    {
        cout<<"cpy constr C2"<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
C2 a(2,3,4);
C2 b=a;
}
```

When I create the object b, the copy constructor is supposed to be called instead of the normal constructor, but it is not. Now I know that a copy constructor should look like

> C(C const& obj){...}

where C is a class, but in this case, I need the other parameters for C1's constructor. Now, my question is, what have I done wrong, or what can I do in order to make the copy constructor work properly?

Comment: On what basis did you reach the conclusion that a copy constructor would not be called? It most certainly will.

Comment: The one you defined as C2(const C2 &a,int u, int v, int w) is not a copy ctor. Default copy ctor is getting called.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I ran the code and the copy constructor is not called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second constructor is not a copy constructor.  A constructor is only a copy constructor if it can be called with a single argument which is the object to be copied from.

Why not:

```
C2(const C2 &a):C1(static_cast<const C1&>(a)), z(a.z)
{
    cout<<"cpy constr C2"<<endl;
}
```

Note that

1. this copy constructor is practically the same as the compiler
   generated one.
2. the `static_cast` is unnecessary (I put it in for
   clarity).